# How to delete '#' sign in angular-ui-router URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the angular-ui-router library and I have a problem with URLs.

I have the following code:

app.js:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('state', {
        url: '/state',
        templateUrl: 'templates/state.html',
        onEnter: function () {
            /*... code ...*/
        }
    })});
```

index.html:

```
<a href="#/state">STATE</a>
```

This works, but when I remove '#' from the `<a>` tag this doesn't work.

How can I delete the '#' sign from the URL?

Comment: I think you'll have to use HTML5 mode, otherwise using the hash for routes is needed

Comment: html5mode=true or html5mode=false

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You need to enable HTML5Mode if you want navigation without hash tags:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

You will also need to tell angular the root URL of your app by adding the following code to the `<head>` of your HTML file:

```
<base href="/">
```

Be aware that support for HTML5 mode depends on the browser. For those who don't support the History API, [Angular will fallback to hashbang](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#fallback-for-legacy-browsers).

Comment: And i have another question. When I paste URL www.example.com/state, I don't have page with expected content. Can I make something with this?

Comment: It depends on your server. You need to show the same view as you would from the angular app root. AngularJs is smart enough to look at the URL and show the appropriate View / Controller. For example, if you usually go on to your app from /angular, you need to handle the case where going to /angular/state doesn't actually map to a real URL but is in fact a route in /angular and show the same view.

Comment: Also don't forget to put a `<base href="/">` tag inside index.html `<head>` section

Comment: Or you can configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with requireBase:false to $locationProvider.html5Mode(): 

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: @SimonBelanger i am using  mvc4 and in that i have created areas for user specific models controller and view my my landing page is in Areas/Admin/View/Home/Index which uses _Layout as master template 
how should i write url in base href ?

Comment: For refresh loading issue add the .htaccess file in your root folder.

Comment: The question uses `app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)` and the accepted answer uses `app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider)` - is that in addition to, or instead of?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using **Angular 1.6+**, you will also need to remove the [`hashPrefix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6/41226167#41226167) from the URL:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // by default '!'
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Don't forget to change the base as well:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    yourApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    //add this line in your routing code   
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider.state('web.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                controller: 'mainController'         
            })
    }
```

in your index.php or index.html in < head > tag insert

```
< base href="/" >
```

for **CodeIgniter** :

```
<base href=" < ?php echo base_url() ?  >" >
```