# Changing Angular UI router app root from "#" to something else

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I implement angular UI router in my app, my view URL appears as :

```
www.example.com/serverpath#/UIRouterPath1
www.example.com/serverpath#/UIRouterPath2
```

Now I want to change to something like

```
www.example.com/serverpath/SPA/UIRouterPath1
www.example.com/serverpath/SPA/UIRouterPath2
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls

Answer (score 1):

By default, AngularJS will route URLs with a hashtag, but you can remove it with $locationProvider.

You will use the $locationProvider module and set html5Mode to true. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider,  $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And for add a base to url in your index file you must use `<base>` tag in the head section. For example

```
<base href="/SPA">
```

In this way when you write one `<a>` tag like this in your html file:

```
<a href="UIRouterPath1">UIRouterPath1</a>
```

it will be linked to: www.example.com/serverpath/SPA/UIRouterPath1

Comment: I did this. But the new base mentioned in the <base> tag is not getting applied, i.e., instead of getting
www.example.com/serverpath/SPA/UIRouterPath1
I am getting 
www.example.com/serverpath/UIRouterPath1

As a result of this even my actual server routes are getting interpreted as angular ui routes.

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad explanation about label <base>. I must said that if you work in angular with routes the value of base is applied in property templateUrl.
For example   

    $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                })

this link to: [Valueofbase]/views/login.html