# Why an angular webapp has root context set to #

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking at existing angular app which can only be loaded if I use root context of #?

e.g. 
loading localhost:8080/hello does not work and returns 404
however, loading localhost:8080/#/hello works.

So how the root context is setup for angular apps by default? How can you change it if you don't want it to be #?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete '#' sign in angular-ui-router URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls)

Comment: That is how angular routing works - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 . you need to change routing config if you want to remove it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with root contexts. You need to get familar with single page apps. All the URLs in such an app don't represent resources on the server. Just routes in the client-side apps. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location