# Always showing "index.html#!" in url on angularjs routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in my angularjs app inside a website project in Visual Studio, but it only works with the route http://localhost/index.html#!/my-page, but I want the route to be only http://localhost/my-page.

Is there  a way to do this?

Here is my routing code:

```
angular.module('nutricaoApp').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('cardapio-paciente');

    $stateProvider
    .state('my-page', {
        url: '/my-page',
        templateUrl: './app/components/my-page.html',
        controller: 'MyPageController'
    });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

<base href="/">
```

[How to delete '#' sign in angular-ui-router URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls)

And config your .htaccess to remove index.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Working example on codepen

https://codepen.io/centrodph/pen/gXGVvz?editors=1010

Comment: It works when I am routing on angularjs, but when I enter the url manually on the browser, it doesn't works.

Comment: I thinks you can fix that with a .htaccess rule

Comment: At now, I am not doing any back-end on my application, this rule could be applied to that case?

Comment: Yes you can upload your .htaccess file on your root folder. The .htaccess rules will apply to the all site.

Comment: But I've been thinking, will angular always make my url look like "www.mysite.com/index.html/my-page.html" by default?

Comment: No, you can use a rewrite rule to convert /index.html/my-page.html to /my-page.html