# Removing # from URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I am using UI-route where state provider is used.
My application is built on AngularJS on the express server(not apache server). 
The problem is the URL of the pages.
URL looks like : 
http://localhost:3006/#!/home

What I want to look like :
http://localhost:3006/home or http://localhost:3006/!/home

Can someone help me to do this?
I search this on Google but I find the solution with apache server.
As well as I use

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But it show this error :

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hashPrefix' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3006/app.js:448:20
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:44:390)
    at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:279)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:418
    at r (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:8:7)
    at g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:180)
    at gb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:46:250)
    at c (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:22:19)
    at Uc (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:22:332)
    at we (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js:21:1
```

Answer (score 0):

[please check this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

add $locationProvider in your config app.js.
after that add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

and last include `<base href="/">` in head of your index.html

Comment: I already done this, not solved the problem

Comment: remove this one`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

Comment: I used $stateProvider

Comment: you should change your code please refer this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls

Comment: if you got success then please upvote my answer