# How to remove # symbol in the angularJs app while running app in local environment?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to remove **#** symbol in my App URL

I tried bellow code:

```
    angular.module('public')
        .config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$locationProvider'];


    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('public', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'src/public/public.html'
        }). ...
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

this code is working in dev server but not working in local server

while running this code:

```
    angular.module('public')
        .config(routeConfig);

    routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$locationProvider'];


    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('public', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'src/public/public.html'
        }). ...
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

after removing the **#** symbol from the url it throws:

> 404 page not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable HTML5Mode if you want navigation without hash tags:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) { 
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);                                   
}]);
```

You will also need to tell angular the root URL of your app by adding the following code to the  of your HTML file:

```
<base href="/">
```

[How to delete '#' sign in angular-ui-router URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls)

Comment: I tried the above code it was not working in localhost:4200