# AngularJS Routing not going to page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I have set up a basic AngularJS page, and I've set up a couple of extra pages, a home page and a login page.

My index.html looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="votee">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      <a href="#/login"> View Login</a>
      <a href="#/home"> View Home</a>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js looks like this

```
var votee = angular.module('votee', ['ionic', 'ngRoute']);
  votee.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
  });
  votee.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      if (window.cordova && window.Keyboard) {
        window.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });
  votee.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {

  });
  votee.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {

  })
```

The HTML pages for Home and Login are in the same directory as index.html, and when clicking on one of the links, it will say http://localhost:8100/#/login, which implies to me that the routing is at least partially correct, however the pages don't load.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [How to delete '#' sign in angular-ui-router URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102815/how-to-delete-sign-in-angular-ui-router-urls) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wouldn't have found that in a million years!